# group by along with totals in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query

```
select role,  count(*) as cases  from ( select
     CASE WHEN r.id = 30 THEN r.name ELSE r.name || ' ' || u.member_id END AS role
    from case_inventory ci, users u, roles r
    where ci.board_id = u.board_id and
          ci.assigned_to = u.io_id and 
          u.role_id = r.id
          and ci.case_id = 40) 
    group by role;
```

Output is :

```
  Role          Cases
  President      1
  Student Member 2
```

I want the totals in the same query. How should I go forward?

```
  Role          Cases
  President      1
  Student Member 2  
  Totals         3
```

Comment: Use `WITH ROLLUP`.

Comment: @The Impaler  got it. thank you.

Comment: Your query is not going to work in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rewrire your query by adding rollup in the query:

```
select nvl(role, 'Totals') role,  count(*) as cases  from ( select
     CASE WHEN r.id = 30 THEN r.name ELSE r.name || ' ' || u.member_id END AS role
    from case_inventory ci, users u, roles r
    where ci.board_id = u.board_id and
          ci.assigned_to = u.io_id and 
          u.role_id = r.id
          and ci.case_id = 40) 
    group by Rollup(role);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column references in a query that references more than one table.

To answer your question *in Oracle*, use `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(role, 'Total') as role, count(*) as cases 
from (select (case when r.id = 30 then r.name else r.name || ' ' || u.member_id
              end_ AS role
    from case_inventory ci join
         users u
         on ci.board_id = u.board_id and
            ci.assigned_to = u.io_id join
         roles r
         on u.role_id = r.id
     where ci.case_id = 40
    ) r
group by grouping sets ( (role), () );
```